# Implement TypeVar('T') every time I use generics or is there an import?

Tags: python, typing

I'd like to annotate functions with generic types like the example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics)

```py
from typing import Sequence, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def first(l: Sequence[T]) -> T:
    return l[0]
```

Do we always have to implement `T` ourselves if we want to use it or is there an import somewhere? Are we supposed to use `_T` from the typing module? As far as I understand variables prefixed with underscore are not meant for public use in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, underscored objects should not be imported from `typing` (and any other standard library), since they are considered as implementation detail.

If we take a look at `typing` module [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8252c52e57283515ace5d4251584255dc5c60eb5/Lib/typing.py#L1410):

```py
# Some unconstrained type variables.  These are used by the container types.
# (These are not for export.)
T = TypeVar('T')  # Any type.
KT = TypeVar('KT')  # Key type.
VT = TypeVar('VT')  # Value type.
T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)  # Any type covariant containers.
V_co = TypeVar('V_co', covariant=True)  # Any type covariant containers.
VT_co = TypeVar('VT_co', covariant=True)  # Value type covariant containers.
T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', contravariant=True)  # Ditto contravariant.
# Internal type variable used for Type[].
CT_co = TypeVar('CT_co', covariant=True, bound=type)

# A useful type variable with constraints.  This represents string types.
# (This one *is* for export!)
AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, str)
```

So even non-underscored `TypeVar`s should not be imported (except `AnyStr` one). And yes, AFAIK we should define those by ourselves if needed.

I'm not aware of any standard way of doing that, but personally I prefer to have a module with-type-hints-only like

**myproject/hints.py**

```py
from typing import TypeVar
...
Domain = TypeVar('Domain')
```

and use it afterwards in other **myproject** modules

```py
from myproject.hints import Domain
...

def first(l: Sequence[Domain]) -> Domain:
    return l[0]
```